# How to insert a picture into a database using C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to insert pictures into a database and I don't know how to write the SQL command to do so.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer this link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-save-insert-Image-in-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

you need to convert your image to byte array and store it into database column and whenever you fatch that byte and generate image on that byte